# SAPUI5 OData v4 Batch Requests Header Parsing

Tags: http-headers, odata, sapui5, odata-v4

I'm trying to implement a UI5 service using an OData v4 backend.
In general my bindings seem to work, however, there seems to be a problem parsing the headers of the batch requests. Parsing the batch parts by skipping the code in the debugger works fine.

In the console I get the following error:

```
2022-10-11 13:14:09.584899 $batch failed - Error: Expected 'OData-Version' header with value '4.0' but received value 'null' in response for http://localhost:8080/odata/$batch
    at h.doCheckVersionHeader (http://localhost:1337/resources/sap/ui/core/library-preload.js:4753:314)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:1337/resources/sap/ui/core/library-preload.js:4786:415)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:1337/resources/sap-ui-core.js:2099:9272)
    at p (http://localhost:1337/resources/sap-ui-core.js:2219:26833)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:1337/resources/sap-ui-core.js:2219:27676)
    at y3 (http://localhost:1337/resources/sap-ui-core.js:2219:84906)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:1337/resources/sap-ui-core.js:2219:87536) sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel`
```

However, inspecting the headers in the developer tools the `OData-Version` header seems to be set

```
HTTP/1.1 202
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
OData-Version: 4.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_63059dbf-3e96-4650-b6b9-c6237b7e3b9e
Content-Length: 3848
Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2022 11:14:06 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

In the function `h.doCheckVersionHeader` only the `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` are aviable.

I start my project via `ui5 serve` and seem to be using version `1.102.1`.
Does anyone know how I can get the requests to work?

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the issue by adding the
`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header to the response: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3613#issuecomment-1274609280

Answer (score 0):

The section "Response Headers" from the documentation topic ["Model Instantiation and Data Access"](https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/#/topic/9613f1f2d88747cab21896f7216afdac) [now](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/commit/103a60ce1b16fccea3e2ec703e171f1941a596bc#diff-8695deb0beff886d1337f4ecc5c1458e8654855f8cff73d849aa87391989db3e) lists headers that need to be added to the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header:

> The OData model processes some of the response headers, namely:
>
> - `DataServiceVersion` (only when consuming an OData V2 service),
> - `Date`,
> - `ETag`,
> - **`OData-Version`**,
> - `Preference-Applied`,
> - `Retry-After`,
> - `SAP-Messages`,
> - `X-CSRF-Token`.
>
> Some SAP applications will also require the processing of `SAP-ContextId`, `SAP-Err-Id`, and `SAP-Http-Session-Timeout`. When using *cross-origin resource sharing* (CORS), it is important to **add all these headers to the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header.**

Also, make sure that values assigned to the headers are syntactically valid. E.g. [no dangling characters](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/issues/216): `OData-Version: 4.0;` → `OData-Version: 4.0`.